# Get all Rows from QUERY() into one cell in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following formula in a spreadsheet:

> =IFERROR( JOIN( CHAR(10), QUERY(Schedule!$A$2:$E, "SELECT C, D, E Where A = '" & B$2 & "' AND B = timeofday '" & text($A4, "HH:MM:SS") & "' AND C = '" & $C$1 & "'", -1)),)

It works great when it returns one row.  It does not work if it returns multiple rows.  How can I get it to use all rows returned with a CHAR(10) included between rows as well as columns.  Basically I want all the returned data separated by line breaks.  So when the QUERY returns

> Item1  Item2  Item3
>
> Item1A Item2A Item3A

it is changed to

> Item1
>
> Item2
>
> Item3
>
> Item1A
>
> Item2A
>
> Item3A

My goal is to put all the returned data in 1 cell with a line break between each item.  Any way I can make this happen?

Here is a [copy of the file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U58oTNTHlec-olsVBQokcrH_I4XMnaDWcfJVP-ESS_g/edit#gid=1731265616). Cells B3 to F4 are good sample cells where the formula reside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is imperfect, it adds extra spaces before each line:

```
  Item1 Item2 Item3
  Item1A Item2A Item3A
^ spaces
```

**Step1**

Get origilal formula + extra column in query:

`=QUERY(data, "SELECT C, D, E, '@@' Where" & ... & "' label '@@' ''", -1)`

The result:

```
  Item1  Item2  Item3  @@
  Item1A Item2A Item3A @@
```

**Step2**

Replace "@@" with char(10)

`=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(step1Formula,"@@",char(10)))`

```
  Item1  Item2   Item3 

  Item1A Item2A  Item3A
                          ^ new lines
```

**Step3**

Use concatenate:

`=ArrayFormula(" "&TRIM(CONCATENATE(" "&B16:E17)))`

**Final formula**

`=ArrayFormula(" "&TRIM(CONCATENATE(" "&SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(Schedule!$A$2:$E, "SELECT C, D, E, '@@' Where A = '" & B$2 & "' AND B = timeofday '" & text($A3, "HH:MM:SS") & IF(OR($C$1 = "*",ISBLANK($C$1)), "", "' AND C = '" & $C$1) &  IF(OR($F$1 = "*",ISBLANK($F$1)), "", "' AND E = '" & $F$1) & "' label '@@' ''", -1),"@@",char(10)))))`

Shared file:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1otcqvkXb5H3WTSi_exKw9UUcRqN8MKBZ5JYCmTLAWdQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: While you didn't get me what I was after, you got me close enough, and also went a little too complicated.  I am after each returned item on a new line.  My final formula is: `=ArrayFormula(TRIM(CONCATENATE(CHAR(10)&QUERY(Schedule!$A$2:$E, "SELECT C, D, E Where A = '" & B$2 & "' AND B = timeofday '" & text($A3, "HH:MM:SS") & IF(OR($C$1 = "*",ISBLANK($C$1)), "", "' AND C = '" & $C$1) &  IF(OR($F$1 = "*",ISBLANK($F$1)), "", "' AND E = '" & $F$1) & "'", -1))))` removing the need for the @@ and SUBSTITUTE and concatenating with CHAR(10) instead of the double spaces.

Comment: I decided to accept this as the answer. After playing a farther, I used the label/@@ portion to place a "line" between the rows as well, making the final formula I used `=IFERROR( ArrayFormula(TRIM(CONCATENATE(CHAR(10)&QUERY(Schedule!$A$2:$E, "SELECT C, D, E, '" & REPT("_", 12) & "' Where A = '" & B$2 & "' AND B = timeofday '" & text($A3, "HH:MM:SS") & IF(OR($C$1 = "*",ISBLANK($C$1)), "", "' AND C = '" & $C$1) &  IF(OR($F$1 = "*",ISBLANK($F$1)), "", "' AND E = '" & $F$1) & "' label '" & REPT("_", 12) & "' ''", -1)))),)` The formula I provided above is the one that actually answers my question.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not an elegant solution, but it will help you in your case. Enter this formula at `B3` and then copy and paste it onto other cells.

```
=iferror(join(char(10), query(Schedule!$A$2:$E, "select C,D,E where A='"&B$2&"' and B=timeofday '"&text($A3, "hh:mm:ss")&"' limit 1 offset 0")),"")
&iferror(char(10)&char(10) & join(char(10), query(Schedule!$A$2:$E, "select C,D,E where A='"&B$2&"' and B=timeofday '"&text($A3, "hh:mm:ss")&"' limit 1 offset 1")),"")
&iferror(char(10)&char(10) & join(char(10), query(Schedule!$A$2:$E, "select C,D,E where A='"&B$2&"' and B=timeofday '"&text($A3, "hh:mm:ss")&"' limit 1 offset 2")),"")
&iferror(char(10)&char(10) & join(char(10), query(Schedule!$A$2:$E, "select C,D,E where A='"&B$2&"' and B=timeofday '"&text($A3, "hh:mm:ss")&"' limit 1 offset 3")),"")
&iferror(char(10)&char(10) & join(char(10), query(Schedule!$A$2:$E, "select C,D,E where A='"&B$2&"' and B=timeofday '"&text($A3, "hh:mm:ss")&"' limit 1 offset 4")),"")
```

Basically you cannot concat result strings with google `query()`, so instead I'd fetch one row at a time using `limit 1 offset 0`, `limit 1 offset 1`, `limit 1 offset 2`, and so on. Maximum is 5 in this case. Sample sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WsOUXHAxfeTt1ESjrxSa8QkfZytBzm6BnHejlj4mQmE/).

[image]

Comment: As you said, this is not elegant.  In my case I do have a known maximum number of rows which may be returned, 10.  It could work, but will get large.  Thank you for the solution, though!  I had forgotten about limiting the return to a single row.